# DocumentFragment vs $('<div/>')

Tags: jquery, documentfragment

Is creating a DocumentFragment, the same as creating a `$('<div/>')`?

E.g.:

```
var fragment = $(document.createDocumentFragment());
```

vs

```
var detached = $('<div/>');
```

I'm unsure about the advantages of using a DocumentFragment like that when detached elements seem very similar.

Comment: a `fragment` is not an html element like a `div`, it can contain html elements but it has no representation in the DOM. [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment). It's usefull when you create a list of elements without add them directly to the DOM (no redraw on each DOM modifications)

Comment: jQuery will not create a document fragment if you build a single element (as in your `$("<div />")` example. It will use `document.createElement()` instead.

Comment: Does wrapping it in `$` do a `document.createElement()` ? `$(document.createDocumentFragment());`, or is it still detached from DOM?

Comment: @AkshayRawat No, it's just a jQuery object that contains your fragment

Comment: When you append a `documentFragment` to the dom, you only add it's content to the dom, not like adding a `div`. If the fragment contains nothing, it add nothing to the dom.